# redirect with special character .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, apache2

i have a little problem to redirect this url :

```
http://www.domain.com/cat,test.html?cri-109=73_82_129_490_524_536_542_547_636_672_775_797_1098_1318_1319_1453&priceMin&priceMax=%2523&cri-115=50_55_99_113_151_644
```

to this

```
http://www.domain.com/cat,test.html?cri-109=73_82_129_490_524_536_542_547_636_672_775_797_1098_1318_1319_1453&priceMin=&priceMax=&cri-115=50_55_99_113_151_644
```

i tried this line to do it but no luck :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)%2523(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escpaing the `%` character with a backslash:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\%2523(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L]
```